# unhandled exception: system.typeInitializationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to navigate to website and send keys. 
It is working fine in development environment/computer. But I am getting error, when im trying to run through different computer.

```
namespace McaidWebToolImport
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the batch number: ");
        string batchnumber = Console.ReadLine();

        if (batchnumber != "")
        {
            IWebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\IEDriverServer\");
            driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com/webtool/physPop.asp?b=" + batchnumber);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver1.Quit();                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Re-run the application with valid batch number");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress Esacpe key (Esc) to exit");                
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);             
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you look about [TypeInitializationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) ??

Comment: @ ryadavilli: i have posted sample code here ...

Comment: Does the folder `C:\IEDriverServer` really exist on the computer?

Comment: yes.. since i have to run it on other PC, I put it there first and trying to run it .

Comment: this might help.. i have tested solution on other pc where VS-2010 is installed. it worked fine but the exe doesnt work where VS-2010 is not available

Answer (score 0):

You might try handling the exception (try/catch), then you can inspect the InnerException and get more detail about what's failing.

Possibly an Assembly that's present on your development machine but not on the target machine.

Comment: Okay... this might help.. i have tested solution on other pc where VS-2010 is installed. it worked fine but the exe doesnt work where VS-2010 is not available.....

Comment: @user1661116, alternatively, there may be info in the Event Log of the target machine.