# C# - Using external CLR DLL

Tags: c#, dll, yeppp

I'm trying to use an external library with my code. I have added it as a reference from within Visual Studio and things like auto-complete works fine, I can see all the available methods while typing code. It also compiles without any warning or errors.

The DLL is within the same directory as the executable.

However, I get this error:

```
"Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to loa
d DLL 'yeppp': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
 0x8007007E)
   at Yeppp.Library.yepLibrary_Init()
   at Yeppp.Library.Init()
   at .cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get this library? Yiu need to ask its author, as the dll has been loaded, but it looks for something else.

Comment: From here: http://www.yeppp.info/

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202543/how-to-solve-system-typeinitializationexception-was-unhandled-exception-in-vb-ne)? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566820/unhandled-exception-system-typeinitializationexception)? You forgot to install that `yeppp`?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.yeppp.info/cs/index.html#GettingStarted

You also need to deploy yeppp.dll as the article says.

Comment: This is exactly how I have set up and deployed the library.

Comment: Then drop yeppp.dll to %windir%\system32 or %windir%\SYSWOW64

Comment: @user9993 Make sure that your Yeppp.dll matches the bitness of your program (i.e. use 32-bit DLL if your program is 32-bit and 64-bit DLL if your program is 64-bit). Alternatively, you may try CLR bundle from  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yeppp.CLR.Bundle

Comment: @MaratDukhan Works fine following your advice about NuGet. Already seeing calculation speed ups!